# Visual Studio Code and git (--separate-git-dir)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository

For personal purposes, I want to have my local git-repositories under a given local - say `/usr/local/gitREPO` - and checkout to another folder.

Such things work with the command `git clone https://REMOTEgit/TEST --separate-git-dir=/usr/local/gitREPO/TEST /home/user/wrk/TEST`

Within the working folder the checkout is done and a  `.git` file containing

```
gitdir: /usr/local/gitREPO/TEST
```

Seems to work. But so sad, MS Visual Studion Code does not recognise that. Am I missing a config-entry for such details?